# How do you handle charitable contributions?

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, widget

Basically, I'm wondering if any of you have put together a for-profit e-commerce site that has had a charity donation option.  We are trying to keep it a separate entity from our inventory and the rest of our books.

We are looking for a tool to easily integrate a $1 or custom amount donation into the checkout.  We run a single-page AJAX checkout with a php/postgres back-end.  Any suggestions would rock.  Our first charity will be Cystic Fibrosis but we're looking to add more later.

Also, if there was a better place to post this, I apologize.  Doctype didn't seem quite right.

Comment: Also, if anyone has a e-commerce best practices go-to area/forum, I would love to hear it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [PayPal Donations](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/donate-intro-outside).

> PayPal Donations is a low cost way for you to accept credit card and bank account donations. Integrate PayPal Donations with your website in a few easy steps.

Comment: It seems a little counter-intuitive to pay for donations.  >.<  I think we'll probably end up adding it as a service to our current total on the order and then expense it out later through the accounting.

I wish there was some service out there that didn't charge to add funds to an approved charity.

Comment: PayPal has reduced fees for 501(c)(3) U.S.-based charities, along with other discount programs for charities in other countries. In the US, you're mostly paying for credit card transaction fees, along with the secure infrastructure PayPal provides.